# andEngine sound issues

Tags: audio, andengine

i am making a musical piano in andEngine and in my code i created two rectangles images and on putting fingers on that they play sound and i used scene.setOnAreaTouch() in my code and within it i had use isActionMoove() and now the problem is when i move the finger it play the sound but it will play the continuous sound and not waiting to stop the first sound.

and here is my code pls help

```
enter code here

public class TouchActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
    private Camera camera;
    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;


    private BitmapTextureAtlas texImage1, texImage2, textimage;
    private TextureRegion regImage1, regImage2;

    private TiledTextureRegion regCat;
    private AnimatedSprite sprCat;

    private static int SPR_COLUMN = 2;
    private static int SPR_ROWS = 2;


    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Sprite sprImage1, sprImage2;

    private Sound sound_piano1, sound_piano2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {


        texImage1 = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 512, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        regImage1 = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(texImage1, this.getAssets(), "gfx/pinksmall.png", 0, 0);
        texImage1.load();


        texImage2 = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 512, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        regImage2 = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(texImage2, this.getAssets(), "gfx/pinksmall.png", 0, 0);
        texImage2.load();


        SoundFactory.setAssetBasePath("sounds/");

        try {
            this.sound_piano1 = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), this,
                    "a4.wav");
            this.sound_piano2 = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), this,
                    "c5.wav");
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
        }








    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        Scene scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));



        sprImage1 = new Sprite(0, 0, regImage1, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        scene.attachChild(sprImage1);

        sprImage2 = new Sprite(50, 0, regImage2, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        scene.attachChild(sprImage2);


        scene.registerTouchArea(sprImage1);
        scene.registerTouchArea(sprImage2);


        scene.setOnAreaTouchListener(new IOnAreaTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, ITouchArea pTouchArea, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

                float X = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
                float Y = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();

//                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
//
//                    if(sprImage1.contains(X,Y)){
//                        sound_piano1.play();
////                        sound_piano2.setLoopCount(0);
//                    }
//
//                    if(sprImage2.contains(X,Y)){
//                        sound_piano2.play();
////                        sound_piano2.setLoopCount(0);
//                    }
//
//
//
//                }
//                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionOutside()) {
//                    if(!sprImage2.contains(X,Y)){
//                        sound_piano2.stop();
//                    }
//                    if(!sprImage1.contains(X,Y)){
//                        sound_piano1.stop();
//                    }
//                }

                if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()){

                    if(!sprImage1.contains(X,Y) ){
                        sound_piano1.stop();
                    }

                    else {
                        sound_piano1.play();
                    }

                    if(!sprImage2.contains(X,Y) ){
                        sound_piano2.stop();
                    }

                    else {
                        sound_piano2.play();
                    }



                }


                return false;
            }
        });

        return scene;
    }

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

        camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(), camera);
        engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);


        return engineOptions;
    }



}
```